# HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type when doing POST

Tags: spring, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

So I was trying to do a `POST` using REST with `Postman` in Chrome, but after I hit send got error

> HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

My code and part of the screen shot is included, the pair for the `hashmap` I tried is `duration` and `150`. I am sure the URL is correct but don't know why the media type is not accepted.

```
@Path("activities")
public class ActivityResource {

    @POST
    @Path("activity")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Activity createActivityParams(MultivaluedHashMap<String,String> formParams){
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know your name is HashMap, so you probably love HashMaps, but have you tried MultivaluedMap? I haven't tested but it's possible the reader just accepts the super type and not subtypes in it's isAcceptable method. This is just a guess. Don't have my toolbox open right now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah so as I suspected, the [`FormMultivaluedMapProvider`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/FormMultivaluedMapProvider.java) (which handles `MultivaluedMap` reading for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type only allows for `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` or `MultivaluedMap`, not `MultivaluedHashMap`, as you have.

Here is the source for the [`isReadable`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/FormMultivaluedMapProvider.java#L77) (which is called when the runtime looks for a `MessageBodyReader` to handle the combination of Java/Content-Type types.

```
@Override
public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
                          Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    // Only allow types MultivaluedMap<String, String> and MultivaluedMap.
    return type == MultivaluedMap.class
            && (type == genericType || mapType.equals(genericType));
}
```

---

As as side note, on the writing side, it's a different story, you can see the [`isWriteable`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/FormMultivaluedMapProvider.java#L95) method, uses `isAssignableFrom`, which if the `isReadable` had, you would be able to use the `MultivaluedHashMap` as your method parameter.

```
@Override
public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
                           Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return MultivaluedMap.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
}
```